How to custom title "Iframe Properties" in Iframe editor plugin jodit-react-pro and remove name, title input
How should I create a custom title "Iframe Properties" in the Iframe editor plugin jodit-react-pro and remove the input fields for "Name" and "Title"?

I tried the following solution to no avail
const customLocalization = {
    en: {
      'Iframe Properties': 'Iframe エディタ',
      Width: '幅',
      Height: '高さ',
      'Show frame border': '枠線を表示する',
      'Image properties': 'Custom Image Properties',
    },
  };

  const defaultConfig = useMemo(
    () => ({
      license: process.env.REACT_APP_JODIT_EDITOR_KEY ?? '',
      language: 'en',
      i18n: customLocalization,
      placeholder: '全角：最大1500文字',
      statusbar: false,
      allowResizeX: false,
      allowResizeY: false,
      defaultLineHeight: 1,
      disablePlugins: ['tune-block', 'add-new-line'],
      buttons,
      buttonsMD: buttons,
      buttonsSM: buttons,
      buttonsXS: buttons,
      uploader: {
        insertImageAsBase64URI: true,
        insertVideoAsBase64URI: true,
      },
      preview: true,
      extraButtons: {
        name: 'insertVideo',
        icon: 'video',
        tooltip: '動画挿入',
        exec: handleExtraButtonClick,
      },
    }),
    []
  ); 

